# Python. variable +=1 is not working as it should be in turtle

Tags: python

I'm trying to make something like a "clicker" on buttons for 2 person's, but my variable +=1 is not working in this program. My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Daniel")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 240)
pen.write("a:0  b: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
     
button_a = Button( text="a")
button_a.place(x=530, y=300)
button_b = Button( text="b")
button_b.place(x=130, y=300)

def button_a():
     score_a+= 1
     pen.clear()
     pen.write("a:{}  b: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
def button_b():
     score_b += 1
     pen.clear()
     pen.write("a:{}  b: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

     
while True:
     wn.update()    
     turtle.onclick(button_a)
     turtle.onclick(button_b)
```

i cant put those variables in def, bcs it would reset all the time(i think), somebody have any idea, opinion on this? Im new in programming, and need to learn a lot.

I have tried using it without def, but i need it when im using turtle.onclick, i dont know how to move from this point.

Comment: The problem is that neither button_a() nor button_b() are being called

Comment: i see where i did wrong with calling buttons, but now it's doing an infinite loop

Comment: @OldBill that's not the issue button_a are being called on `turtle.onclick(button_a)` I solve the issue below and I test it its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with  `variable += 1`. Its not working because of scope issue and not defind commend to buttons. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Daniel")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)
score_a = 0
score_b = 0

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 240)
pen.write("a:0  b: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))



def button_a_1():
   print("hello")
   global score_a
   score_a += 1
   pen.clear()
   pen.write("a:{}  b: {}".format(score_a, score_b), 
   align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


def button_b_1():
   global score_b
   score_b += 1
   pen.clear()
   pen.write("a:{}  b: {}".format(score_a, score_b), 
   align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


button_a = Button(text="a", command=button_a_1)
button_a.place(x=530, y=300)
button_b = Button(text="b", command=button_b_1)
button_b.place(x=130, y=300)

while True:
   wn.update()
   turtle.onclick(button_a_1)
   turtle.onclick(button_b_1)
```

Comment: It helped with using variable, still the program dont counting actual score, it still stays at 0 :/

Comment: That's not the issue

Comment: there were multiple issues like scope issues and not defined buttons command action. I update my answer kindly check now it's working.

Comment: do accept that answer. So it help others I they get same error.

Comment: i just did  that :), Thanks again

Comment: My pleasure always to be there to help and contribute to the community.

Comment: This is a very bad implementation because it causes one CPU to spin at 100%. Not the kind of community contribution that helps anyone

Comment: Yes, You are totally right but he is a beginner so it's okay to be just working.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Button_a do this :

```
def button_a(value):
   value += 1
   pen.clear()
   pen.write("a:{}  b: {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

button_a(score_a)
```